# C: Heap sort algorithm, delete & insert

Tags: c, arrays, heap, heapsort

So I'm to write a heap data structure for class, and it's supposed to implement heap sort using only insert and delete operations.

It works .. for smaller sets of ints (size 10 and below).
However, when I input a large set of numbers(100+) in, the result is only semi sorted..

Here's my insert method:

```
 void insert(heapHndl H, int priority) {
     // Makes sure heap has enough room for new element.
     assert(!isFull(H));
     // Increase the current size.
     H->currentSize++;
     // Add to array.
     int pos = H->currentSize;
     // Work up.
     while (pos > 1 && priority < H->array[pos/2]) {
         swap (H, pos, pos/2);
         pos /= 2;
     }
     H->array[pos] = priority;
 }
```

Here's my delete method:

```
 void deleteMax(heapHndl H) {
     // Makes sure the heap is not empty.
     assert(!heapEmpty(H));

     int root = 1;
     // Swap the root and last element.
     swap(H, root, H->currentSize);
     H->array[H->currentSize] = -1;
     H->currentSize--;

     // Work your way down from the root.
     while(root != H->currentSize) {
         int leftChild = 2*root;
         int rightChild = 2*root + 1;
         int minChild;
         // If root is smaller than children..
         if (H->array[root] <= H->array[leftChild] &&
                 H->array[root] <= H->array[rightChild])
             break;
         // If at a leaf node.
         if (rightChild > H->currentSize){
             if (leftChild >= H->currentSize)
                 break;
             else minChild = leftChild;
         } else {
             // Determines which child to swap with.
             if (H->array[leftChild] <= H->array[rightChild])
                 minChild = leftChild;
             else minChild = rightChild;
         }
         swap(H, root, minChild);
         root = minChild;
     }
 }
```

Here's heapHndl.

```
 typedef struct HeapStruct {
     int maxSize;
     int currentSize;
     int *array;
 } HeapStruct;

typedef HeapStruct* heapHndl;
```

I can't seem to figure out what other cases I'm missing for the delete method. I'm pretty sure my insert method is fine (manual checking). Thanks for the help.
Edit: ignore the name, deleteMax. It's actually a min heap. Root is the smallest integer.

Comment: Can we see the details of `heapHndl` ? `int root = 1;` is very suspicious.

Comment: Int root = 1, because the array starts at 1. That way, leftChild = 2*root does not = 0, if root = 0.

Comment: I do not see where you are allocating memory for HeapStruct member  `int *array;`  and yet I see statements like: ` H->array[pos/2])` and ` H->array[pos/2])`  Have you used any malloc() or calloc() calls? If so, how much memory did you allocate?

Comment: @ryyker, tmp->array = malloc(sizeof(int) * (maxSize +1 ));

Comment: @user3288944 - In the context of your post, there are no `m(c)alloc()` statements.  Nor is there a `tmp->array`.  It would help to see them in context.  You might re-think how you are presenting this question, and after doing some of your own debugging, if the problem persists, re-post.  ***[Here are some suggestions on how to improve a post](http://www.sscce.org/)***.

Answer (score 1):

The following two lines are definitely a problem

```
     if (leftChild > H->currentSize || rightChild > H->currentSize)
         break;
```

The loop is not allowed to break if one of the children is missing, only if both children are missing.  If the right child is missing, you must still check, and potentially swap with the left child.

---

Edit: On the other hand, if the parent node is the least of the three (parent,left,right), then the loop does need to break.

Comment: I fixed that, but still the same problem. Any other suggestions? Thanks. Is a while loop possible? Or should I make it a recursive function?

Comment: @user3288944 You can definitely do it with a while loop. Can you append the modified code to the question?

Comment: @user3288944 I've updated the answer with another observation.

Comment: If my insert function is implemented properly, is it ever possible for the parent node to be smaller than its child?

Comment: Update: That fixed the problem. So I guess it is possible for the parent to be smaller than its child.

Comment: Yes, because the first thing the delete function does is take the element from the end of the array and move it to the root position. That element can have any relationship to it's children.

Comment: Update: I tested with a size of 50,000 ints, and everything seems to be in order EXCEPT the last two elements.. I think it has something to do with the comparisons, (>) vs (>=)

Comment: @user3288944  Meaning that the last two are correct relative to the first 49998, but swapped with respect to each other? Also, what's the code look like now?  Edit: I agree with your theory about (>) vs (>=).

Comment: Meaning, that the first 49998 are correct, but the last two are switched. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Alright, I'll let you figure it out from here.  The problem now is that when you check "If root is smaller than children", you are potentially reading from beyond the end of the array. So it's all in the details, but you have to be strict about checking whether the left child and right child are valid indexes into the array.

Comment: Hmm, still can't figure it out.. The last two are out of order.